# Crystal Report Changing Data Source Location Removes Fields from Report and Parameters

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that uses a stored procedure to return the fields that are displayed in the report. The report was tested using data from my test db.  Once the report was completed, I copied the stored procedure to my live database in preparation to update the report to point to live.

The issue I'm having is when I try to set the datasource location of the stored procedure within Crystal so it points to my live database, the fields and the parameters all disappear from the report.

Comment: All fields or some disappear? This usually occurs when CR cannot find those fields in the new data source location - are you certain does fields exist on the live DB?

Comment: Did you really use the "set database location" or did removed the data source and then added the new one?

Comment: They all disappeared, along with the Parameter.

Comment: I used Set Database Location.